# SSIS 2008R2 Data Driven Variable Values

Tags: ssis

I am fairly new to SSIS and have set myself a challenging first project, creating a data driven package framework. My current challenge is that I want to store the values of variables for my various packages in a table and then load them. So for instance, the SSIS package might be processing records between 2 dates. I would have two records in a parameters table:

```
ParmName   ParmValue
--------   ---------
DateFrom   2013-01-01
DateTom    2013-01-31
```

These variables names will exist in the package, I just need to load them. In a false start, I tried using an Execute SQL Task but this didn't work. I assume I need a Script Task C# to do this but I don't know C#. Wondering if anyone could give me a pointer to where I can find some code similar to what I am trying to do. Just to make it a bit clearer, in pseudo code I ebevision a process like

```
Dataset = Select * from PkgParms where PckID = ?
FOR EACH DataSet.Record
   SET (DataSet.Record.ParmName.Value) = (DataSet.Record.ParmValue.Value)
```

If this is not doable or I am in over my head please just let me know
Thanks
Steve

Comment: first hit: http://blog.boxedbits.com/archives/8

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done in `SSIS` - `Package Configurations`. Follow the wizard for `SQL Server` configuration type.
You can find some tutorials how to do it, but in general you'll need 2 new columns:

1. `packagepath` with values like:

   `\Package.Variables[User::DateFrom].Properties[Value]`
2. `configurationfilter` which will have same values for both dates, e.g. `Dates`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am currently using a config file to store the connection details to my framework's package data but for the rest of the package related 'settings' I need it to come from the tables. My reason is that information being stored in tables provides me with a) simpler/dynamic documentation via SSRS reporting, so settings can be checked via report as opposed to having to access the package source code  b) after providing a UI, I can to put some power back into the users hands so that they can change parameters value as/if needed.

Comment: this is the 'table' way

Comment: I will have another look at the configuration stuff, I thought it would only work with xml files - Thanks!